# How to add elements from a list to a dictioanry as values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to write verb conjugator and I've found dictioanry the best way.
I created list of endings and the list of conjugated forms of a given word.
In a dictionary persons names are keys and now I want to import the list elements to be the dictionary values.

I wrote stuff like this:

```
def conjugar_indicativo_presente(word):

endings_ar = ['o', 'as', 'a', 'amos', 'am']
endings_ir = ['o', 'es', 'e', 'imos', 'em']
endings_er = ['o', 'es', 'e', 'emos', 'em']
persons = ['Eu/I', 'Tu/You', 'Ele/Ela/você/He/She/It', 'Nós/We', "Else/Elas/vocês/They"]

conjugated_forms = []
final = dict()

if not isinstance(word, str):
    return 'Palavra incorreta/Incorrect word'

if word.endswith('ar'):
    for ending in endings_ar:
        conjugated_forms.append(word[:-2] + ending)
        list = zip(persons, conjugated_forms)
        final_conjugated_forms = dict(list)  
    return final_conjugated_forms
elif word.endswith('er'):
    for ending in endings_er:
        conjugated_forms.append(word[:-2] + ending)
        list = zip(persons, conjugated_forms)
        final_conjugated_forms = dict(list)  
    return final_conjugated_forms
elif word.endswith('ir'):
    for ending in endings_ir:
        conjugated_forms.append(word[:-2] + ending)
        list = zip(persons, conjugated_forms)
        final_conjugated_forms = dict(list)  
    return final_conjugated_forms
```

I tried to this other way than converting list into dictionary, by for loop
but I didn't make it
Do you have any hint what should I use?
Some more (let's say) automated way?

Regards

Comment: It's not clear what your expected output or your actual problem is... please have a look at how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Except for the indentation, your example seems to be working as expected. For ```conjugar_indicativo_presente('casar')```, for example, I get the following output ```{'Eu/I': 'caso', 'Tu/You': 'casas', 'Ele/Ela/você/He/She/It': 'casa', 'Nós/We': 'casamos', 'Else/Elas/vocês/They': 'casam'}``` as expected. But one thing I noticed you are missing is how to deal with verbs like ```ir```, ```vir``` and all those two letters long ones.

Comment: Hi,I'm sorry for not have explained the problem clear. I mean, how to assign elements of a list as values by, for example, iterating keys. I'm not sure if I'm looking for a hole where this hole does not exists. Regarding missing verbs, I didn't already do this because I'm at the stage of creating a frame for a programme, I will add them later.

Comment: I also don't understand the problem. But I suggest you to remove the 3 blocks that look almost the same by using a dict with `ar`/`ir`/`er` as keys and lists of endings as values. Also, note that the lines: `list = zip(persons, conjugated_forms); final_conjugated_forms = dict(list)` don't have to be in loops.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how take elements from a list and make of them a dictionary. As a matter of fact, I did it by myself by ipping list, etc but I sure that it's possible by looping and I thought that my solution is not really good. You're right Georgy, I'l take your advice, it's a great hint. Regards.